# How to Delete set of XML node in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Below is my XML file

```
<MultiCentreDeals>
  <DealItem>
    <ID>24</ID>
      <Days>
        <Day>
           <DayID>24-1</DayID>
           <DayTitle>Day 13</DayTitle>
           <Title>Meeting Point</Title>
           <HotelName>15</HotelName>
        </Day>
        <Day>
           <DayID>24-2</DayID>
           <DayTitle>Day 2</DayTitle>
           <Title>Departure to Test</Title>
           <HotelName>54</HotelName>
        </Day>
       </Days>
  </DealItem>
</MultiCentreDeals>
```

I want to delete the XML node set belong to ID 24 and DayID 24-2. Can anyone explain how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

XDocument is your friend.

```
// Parse your XML string
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// Find the first child of type "Day", whose child of type "DayID" has the value "24-2"
var toRemove = doc.Root
    .Descendants("Day")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element("DayID").Value == "24-2"); 

// Remove it
toRemove?.Remove();

string result = doc.ToString();
```